# step, min, and max HTML5 attributes don't work in iOS Safari on a time input

Tags: android, ios, html

I'm writing a time picker for an application, and I want to use the native iOS and Android time pickers.  I'm using a simple html input:

```
<input type="time" step="1800" min="08:00" max="23:30">
```

I have a [link](http://jsfiddle.net/jradakov/efeL1e8k/1/) to a very simple JSFiddle that I used to test on my iPhone.

All I'm really interested in is specifying a minimum time. A step would be nice, but not necessary.

Google Calendar seems to have it working, but I'm not sure if they are using a `select` with `options` or what.

Is this possible with the native iOS time picker?

Comment: have you solved it?

Comment: I don't think there is a solution, it just isn't supported. You need to work around it.